# readtable() when a string ends with \

Tags: csv, julia

When I read in a csv file containing

> "number","text"
>
> 1,"row1text\"
>
> 2,"row2text"

with the commands

```
using DataFrames

readtable(filename.csv)
```

I get a dataframe with only one row. Apparently, the backslash at the end of the text in the first row is a problem. Is this expected behavior? Is there an alternative way where this problem is avoided?

As a side note: The following works fine (i.e. I get two rows) but is obviously impractical for reading in big files

```
    df = csv"""

    "number","text"

    1,"row1text\"

    2,"row2text"

    """
```

Comment: Second one is unexpected for me. Difference is cause by IOBuffer (which escapes) used in macro csv_str. Although you like this behavior, it is probably bug.

Answer (score 2):

Since the backslash is the escape character by default, it escapes the quote mark and messes everything up. One workaround would be to use the `CSV.jl` package and specify a different escape character:

```
julia>  using CSV

julia> CSV.read("filename.csv", escapechar = '~')
2×2 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ number │ text        │
├─────┼────────┼─────────────┤
│ 1   │ 1      │ "row1text\" │
│ 2   │ 2      │ "row2text"  │
```

But then you have to make sure the `~` chars are not escaping something else. There might be a better way of doing this, but this would be one hack to get around the problem.

Another way would be to process the data row by row. Here is a way over-complicated example of doing so:

```
julia> open("filename.csv", "r") do f
           for (i, line) in enumerate(eachline(f))
               if i == 1
                 colnames = map(Symbol, split(line, ','))

                 global df = DataFrame(String, 0, length(colnames))

                 rename!(df,
                       Dict([(old_name, new_name) for (old_name, new_name) in zip(names(df), colnames)]))

               else
                   new_row = map(String, split(replace(line, "\\\"", "\""), ','))
                   # replace quotes around vales
                   new_row = map(x -> replace(x, "\"", ""), new_row)
                   push!(df, new_row)
               end
           end
       end

julia> df
2×2 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ "number" │ "text"     │
├─────┼──────────┼────────────┤
│ 1   │ "1"      │ "row1text" │
│ 2   │ "2"      │ "row2text" │
```

Comment: Second one is hack too (IMHO worse) for example: `println("\"escaped backslash problem \\\\\"")` or `println("\"new line \n problem \"")`

Comment: it is definitely a hack and not a very good one either. Just throwing it out there, so maybe someone can improve it or spur new solutions.